# PiFM on another GPIO

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pifm

I want to make my own Pi Radio using PiFM on my Raspberry Pi 2, but i have a display already mounted on pin 4. Can i use some other GPIO pin for mounting antenna ? And if i can, which is the best GPIO for broadcasting ?

Thank you for all of your help

Comment: I didn't realise someone had managed to get PiFM working on the Pi2.

Comment: Really ? Why not ?

Comment: Because the last time I bothered looking was shortly after the Pi2 was released.  I've had a quick look and the Pi2 PiFM version seems to have dropped DMA so won't be as good as the earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, i just saw it on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/2wcgpp/

Comment: What about this ? https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter On different GPIO ?

Comment: I see no reason why GPIO 6 (clock 2) or GPIO 20 (clock 0) could not be used.  You could possibly use GPIO 5 and 21 (clock 1) on an A+.  The problem will be in finding someone willing and capable of making the needed changes.  Although changing the clock will be trivial compared to getting DMA to work.